# How to create new column from specific information in excisting column?

Tags: r

So I have a column like this

```
stimulus
005_y_f_n_b_m
004_m_m_n_b_m
005_y_f_s_b_m
```

And I want to create a new column like this:

```
baseFace
005
004
005
```

How do I extract one small peace of information from the existing column to a new column? My goal is to split the stimulus column into several columns (spreading out all the information from the column like y, f, n etc since they all have a specific meaning).

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: `df1 <- tidyr::separate(df, stimulus, c('baseFace', paste0('col', 1:5)), sep = '_')`

Comment: Oh my you're fast! Thanks a lot man! It did the job perfectly. made my day (Y)